# EF Core Json support with List

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to store a Json list in a DB column leveraging EF Core 7 Json support? I tried without success.

I have these classes (simplified):

```
public class StateData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DemandId { get; set; }
    public List<SateItem>? MenuState { get; set; }
    public int? LastMenuItem { get; set; }
}

public class StateItem
{
    public int SideMenuItemId { get; set; }
    public int StateDataId { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; } = null!;
    }
}
```

And this `DbContext`:

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}

public DbSet<StateData> StateData { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new StateDataConfiguration());
}
```

With configuration:

```
public class StateDataConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<StateData>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<StateData> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsMany(d => d.MenuState, builder =>
        {
            builder.ToJson();
        });
    }
}
```

The goal is to store the list of `StateItem`'s in the `MenuState` column as a Json array. If I just store `StateItem`'s in a table, it works. As soon as I make them an owned class, I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Object' cannot be used for assignment to type 'System.Int32'

I think, the problem has to do with primary key definition. But if I try to define primary keys, EF insists that keys need to be implicitly defined.

So, is it even possible to store Json array with EF Core's Json support?

Comment: I haven't tried it out (yet) but EF (core) 7 has added support for JSON columns https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef7-release-candidate-2/

Comment: I had same problem with EF Core 7, and workaround was to rename the 'id' property to something else, in the owned list object.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, where my JSON class had an ID column. Maybe EF Core is trying to autoinsert something in to this? Worked when I removed it. Is it possible that it's interpreting your "SideMenuItemId" and "StateDataId" columns as ID columns? What if you rename them to StateDataIdentifier or something?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34571676)

Comment: I had same problem, and solved it by renaming property to not have 'id' in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, using [JsonProperty.EFCore](https://github.com/maxchistt/JsonProperty.EFCore) can solve your problem. You can install it as a nuget [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonProperty.EFCore).

In your case:

```cs
using JsonProperty.EFCore;

public class StateData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DemandId { get; set; }
    public JsonList<SateItem> MenuState { get; set; } = new();
    public int? LastMenuItem { get; set; }
}
```

Other usage example:

```cs
using JsonProperty.EFCore;

//Create product
var product = new Product() { Name = "Car" };

//AddRange
product.Attributes.AddRange(new Dictionary<string, object>() {
    //You can add values ​​of different types if the base type is object 
    {"MaxSpeed",300},{ "Engine capacity",3.5}, { "ElectroCar",false }
});

//Add
product.Attributes.Add("Color", "Red");

//Edit
product.Attributes.Edit(attrs=>{
    attrs["Color"] = "Blue";
    return attrs;
});

//Entity model
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //Json container property. Same type as JsonDictionary<string,object>
    public JsonDictionary Attributes{ get; set; } = new();
}
```